# Newtonsoft.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T> works on one child object but not the rest

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine, json.net, deserialization

This one is a real puzzler.

I use Newtonsoft.Json in Unity to serialize a list of HexTile, each of which has a Hexagon, and it produces this JSON that looks good and deserializes in my Node app just fine
Data source:

```
PolySphere sphere = new PolySphere(Vector3.zero, WorldManager.worldScale, WorldManager.worldSubdivisions);
JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
serializer.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(Application.dataPath+"\\Resources\\baseworld.json"))   // Note DO NOT use any encoding options
using (JsonWriter writer = new JsonTextWriter(sw))
{
    serializer.Serialize(writer, sphere);
}
```

^ That produces this (good) JSON:

```
{
  "hexTiles": [
    {
      "index": 0,
      "height": 0.0,
      "hexagon": {
        "center": {
          "x": 0.561780632,
          "y": 0.5952229,
          "z": -0.574553967
        },
        "normal": {
          "x": 0.561780632,
          "y": 0.5952229,
          "z": -0.574553967
        },
        "v1": {
          "x": 0.561780632,
          "y": 0.5952229,
          "z": -0.574553967
        },
        "v2": {
          "x": 17.0217762,
          "y": 17.6508,
          "z": -18.0395374
        },
        "v3": {
          "x": 16.5437584,
          "y": 18.1888123,
          "z": -17.94959
        },
        "v4": {
          "x": 16.6196823,
          "y": 18.6517467,
          "z": -17.3958359
        },
        "v5": {
          "x": 17.17278,
          "y": 18.5775471,
          "z": -16.9318352
        },
        "v6": {
          "x": 17.6508,
          "y": 18.0395355,
          "z": -17.0217762
        },
        "isPentagon": false,
        "scale": 30.4333477
      },
      "type": 0,
      "neighbors": [
        1,
        2,
        3,
        4,
        9,
        10
      ],
      "passable": true
    }
  ]
}
```

However the result does not deserialize back into PolySphere correctly.

```
TextAsset text = Resources.Load<TextAsset>("baseworld");
PolySphere baseWorld = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PolySphere>(text.text);
// The baseWorld.hexTiles[0].hexagon.center is Infinity, as shown by logging:
Debug.Log(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(baseWorld));
```

Debug.Log after ^ reparsing in Unity:

```
{"hexTiles":[
  {
    "index":0,"height":0.0,
    "hexagon":{
      "center":{"x":"Infinity","y":"Infinity","z":"-Infinity"},
      "normal":{"x":0.561780632,"y":0.5952229,"z":-0.574553967},
      "v1":{"x":"Infinity","y":"Infinity","z":"-Infinity"},
      "v2":{"x":"Infinity","y":"Infinity","z":"-Infinity"},
      "v3":{"x":"Infinity","y":"Infinity","z":"-Infinity"},
      "v4":{"x":"Infinity","y":"Infinity","z":"-Infinity"},
      "v5":{"x":"Infinity","y":"Infinity","z":"-Infinity"},
      "v6":{"x":"Infinity","y":"Infinity","z":"-Infinity"},
      "isPentagon":false,"scale":"Infinity"
    },
    "type":0,
    "neighbors":[1,2,3,4,9,10],
    "passable":true
  }
]}
```

polySphere.hexTiles[0].hexagon.normal parses correctly but *center, v1, v2, etc all come out as {infinity, infinity, -infinity}* **WHY?**

You'll notice that `center`, `normal`, and `v1` are all equivalent so I know it's not a problem parsing the values. The original JSON appears to be formatted correctly *and* it works in Node. So what's going on here?

Original class structure:

```
[Serializable]
public class PolySphere
{
  public List<HexTile> hexTiles;
}
[Serializable]
public class HexTile
{
  public int index;
  public float height = 1;
  public Hexagon hexagon;
  public int type;
  public int[] neighbors;
}

[Serializable]
public class Hexagon
{
  public SerializableVector3 center, normal, v1, v2, v3, v4, v5, v6;
  public bool isPentagon;
  private float _scale;
  public float scale { get{return _scale;}
  set{
        v1 /= v1.magnitude;
        v1 *= value;
        v2 /= v2.magnitude;
        v2 *= value;
        v3 /= v3.magnitude;
        v3 *= value;
        v4 /= v4.magnitude;
        v4 *= value;
        v5 /= v5.magnitude;
        v5 *= value;
        v6 /= v6.magnitude;
        v6 *= value;
        center = (v1 + v2 + v3 + v4 + v5 + v6) / 6f;
        _scale = center.magnitude;
    }
```

}
}

```
[System.Serializable]
 public struct SerializableVector3
 {
    public float x, y, z;
}
```

**tl;dr** One SerializableVector3 out of 8 in my Hexagon class deserializes correctly, the rest all come out as `Infinity`

Comment: 3) `FloatParseHandling` controls how floating point numbers are parsed *when not explicitly specified in the data model*, e.g. when parsing to `JToken` or `dynamic`.  It should have no effect on how properties explicitly typed as `float` are deserialized from a JSON string.

Comment: Hi @dbc, thank you so much for your interest. I've updated the question with more thorough examples. Complete source code to reproduce would be many MB but I provided as complete example using actual output data as I could.

Comment: Can't reproduce on .NET Core 3.1.5, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/5LlWnZ.  Perhaps there's some Unity-specific problem parsing the `float` fields?  Can you try changing them to `double` and re-testing? Or changing them to auto-properties and re-testing?

Comment: I tried using double and auto fields, downgrading to Json.net 3.5 and upgrading to 4.5, also tried pasting the string literal given in my question (with escaped quotes), still getting the same infinity error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trial and error, I discovered the problem was with the Hexagon.scale property. By removing it from serialization the rest of the Deserialize began to work properly.